# start an activity with a custom keyboard

Tags: android

I'm working on an application that contains an activity "MainActivity" this activity contains 9 edittext and this activity connect to the custom keyboard that contains number buttons from 0 to 9 and three button (delete, replay and help) all works perfectly but el rest two buttons (replay and help) I want to click on the button play again (new activity) activity MainActivity restart ... help me please

Comment: post your code first plz

Answer (score 0):

Inside your code, first `findViewById` your replay button, then add a OnClickListener like below.

```
Button replay = findViewById(...);
replay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent restartIntent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(restartIntent)
        }
    });
```